# Number to word program

Tags: c, string

I need to write a program that prints the lowercase English word corresponding to the number (e.g., one for 1, two for 2, etc.). If n>9, print: *Greater than 9*.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
    {
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    
    char keySet[9][5] = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};
    
    if (n > 9)
    {
        printf("Greater than 9");
    }
    else
    {
        n -= 1;
        puts(keySet[n]);
    }
}
```

For a positive int n, do the following:

- If [1 ≤ n ≤ 9] print the lowercase English word corresponding to the number (e.g., one for 1, two for 2, etc.)
- If n>9, print Greater than 9

---

Behavior:

**Input**: 8

**Output**: eightnine

Desired behavior:

**Input**: 8

**Output**: eight

---

Basically, this is only happening with every string having 5 characters, to be exact.

Like "three" & "seven"

Behavior:

**Input**: 7

**Output**: seveneightnine

---

When variable char keySet is defined like `char keySet[9][6]` it works as expected...

Putting value more than 5 works but not 5 itself
not clear about the issue

Comment: The string "eight" requires 6 bytes to store.  It won't fit in an array of size 5.

Comment: @WilliamPursell thank you for such a quick help

Comment: Remember, in C string needs a terminator (`0`-byte at the end of the string). Reason is that C is not object oriented and string is technically a buffer.

Comment: I suggest you add a `"zero"` element and have `char keySet[10][6]`. You'll need that to report the number `0` even if it's not used elsewhere. And you won't have to make confusing adjustments for array index offset.

Answer (score 3):

You aren't giving the compiler enough room to store the strings.  The
string "eight" needs to be stored in an array of size (at least) 6 so that there is room for the null terminator.

That is: `char a[6] = "eight"` is the same as `char a[6] = {'e', 'i', 'g', 'h', 't', '\0' };` and `char b[5] = "eight"` is the same as `char b[5] = { 'e', 'i', 'g', 'h', 't' };`.  In these cases, `a` is a properly null terminated string, but `b` is not a string and passing it to `printf` as the target of a `%s` format specifier is undefined behavior.

Fortunately, you can avoid this problem by letting the compiler count for you with something like:

```
char *keySet[] = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};
```